# Starting and ending position of swiper?

Tags: swiper.js

I'm wondering if there's a way to position a swiper (slider) that is offset from center. So not all the way across the screen initially, nor in the center, but offset. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**SOLVED!** I needed to add the parameters:

```
slidesOffsetAfter: n // desire number
```

**OR**

```
slidesOffsetBefore: n // desire number
```

**Source:** https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api